# Querying extended properties in SQL Server with CS_AS Collation Does not Provide Correct Results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation

I have two databases, one with a collation of `Latin1_General_CI_AI` and the other with `Latin1_General_CS_AS`.

Both databases have an extended property called `Version` and both are set to **1**.

[image]

[image]

If I run the following code:

```
IF ((SELECT value FROM sys.extended_properties WHERE name = 'Version') <> '1')
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Wrong Version', 16, 1);
END
```

I get the error "Wrong Version" on the database with the `CS_AS` collation, but not on the database with the `CI_AI` collation.  I

I would expect not to get an error on either.

To make it stranger, if I run:

```
SELECT value 
FROM sys.extended_properties 
WHERE name = 'Version'
```

I get the value of 1 on both databases. So I am not sure why I am getting the error returned.

I also tried running `collate` which also did not help

```
   IF ((SELECT value FROM sys.extended_properties WHERE name = 'Version' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI) <> 1)
    BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('Wrong Version',16,1);
    END
```

Comment: Considering it's the value 1, why not compare it to the `int` `1`, rather than the `varchar` `'1'`?

Comment: Hi @ThomA As part of my testing, I have tried `int` `1` and also tried `!=` instead of `<>` to see if it helps, but it is the same issue.

Comment: Try `CAST(value AS int)` or `CAST(value AS varchar(10))` so you aren't doing comparisons against sql_variant. e.g. see https://dbfiddle.uk/Ect2BS0O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
(SELECT value FROM sys.extended_properties WHERE name = 'Version') <> '1'
```

The `'1'` gets implicitly cast to `sql_variant` (as that has higher data type precedence)

This will only compare as equal [if the collation of the strings is effectively equal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#comparing-sql_variant-values).

> When sql_variant values of the char, varchar, nchar, or nvarchar data
> types are compared, their collations are first compared based on the
> following criteria: LCID, LCID version, comparison flags, and sort ID.
> Each of these criteria are compared as integer values, and in the
> order listed. If all of these criteria are equal, then the actual
> string values are compared according to the collation.

```
SELECT 'Returns a row'
WHERE  CAST('1' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS AS SQL_VARIANT) <> 
       CAST('1' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI AS SQL_VARIANT)
```

You can do

```
(SELECT CAST(value AS varchar(10)) FROM sys.extended_properties WHERE name = 'Version') <> '1'
```

to convert the value to string first and then get the usual string comparison semantics (without having to worry about what collation was used when the extended property value was first stored)

Answer (score 1):

You can use cast value to varchar and use collate   to solve the problem

```
use [TestDB1]
   IF ((SELECT cast( value  as varchar(100)) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS FROM sys.extended_properties WHERE name = 'Version' ) <> '1')
    BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('Wrong Version',16,1);
    END


use [TestDB2]
   IF ((SELECT cast( value  as varchar(100)) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS FROM sys.extended_properties WHERE name = 'Version' ) <> '1')
    BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('Wrong Version',16,1);
    END
```

You can create DataBases and addextendedproperty  with the following statements:

```
CREATE DATABASE [TestDB1]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'TestDB1', FILENAME = N'C:\1\TestDB1.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'TestDB1_log', FILENAME = N'C:\1\TestDB1_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI 

 USE [master]
GO
EXEC [TestDB1].sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'Version', @value=N'1' 
GO

 CREATE DATABASE [TestDB2]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'TestDB2', FILENAME = N'C:\1\TestDB2.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'TestDB2_log', FILENAME = N'C:\1\TestDB2_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS 


  USE [master]
GO
EXEC [TestDB2].sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'Version', @value=N'1' 
GO
```